Is this kind of group always a semidirect of these vector spaces?
Suppose $G$ is a group and $\forall x, y \in G$, $x^6 = e$ and $x^2 y^2 = y^2 x^2$. This induces the short exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow V \rightarrow G \rightarrow W \rightarrow 0$$
where $V$ resp. $W$ are abelian with exponent $3$ resp. $2$; $V$ here is all the "squares": note that $x^2 y^2 = (x^4 y^4)^2$. Does this short exact sequence necessarily right split?

Split in which sense? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma#Counterexample

@AnneBauval See the title of this question. (I mean that $G = V \rtimes W$, i.e. the map $G \rightarrow W$ has an inverse.)

All the required information should be in the body of the post.

@ArturoMagidin In the context of non-abelian groups, I would think it would be clear what I mean, but sure.

Exact sequences of this type are classified by the group cohomology $H^2(W,V)$. When $W$ is finite, we have $|W|=3^n$. Since multiplication by $3$ is an isomorphism of $V$, this implies that $H^2(W,V)=0$ by Brown Group Cohomology III.10.1. This cohomology vanishing then implies that all such exact sequences split. When $W$ is infinite, I do not know if similar ideas apply.

@Snacc This shouldn't be a comment but an answer

Perhaps "$3$ resp $2$" ought to be "$2$ resp $3$"?
